# How can I tell if a text input field dom node does *not* have a selection with javascript?

Tags: javascript, dom-node

When I check `inputFieldDomNode.selectionStart` it always returns some number, even if it does not have a text selection and there's no caret in it. So how can I tell if it *doesn't* have a text selection?

Answer (score 0):

At least window-globally, you can use [`Selection.isCollapsed`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection.isCollapsed)

```
window.getSelection().isCollapsed
```

Despite the compatibility table, I have found it to be working in Chrome, and apparently it's been supported since [IE 9](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ff974692%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) as well.

Comment: It would seem that only indicates whether or not a range of text is selected, vs there just being a caret on the page somewhere. A. this doesn't help me get any information about a particular input field, and B. it doesn't help me figure out if the caret is in a field.

Comment: @BT isn't that just a matter of focus? If nothing is selected, you're good. If something is selected, it can only be in your input field as long as it has focus.

Comment: Things can be selected without having focus.

Comment: In input fields? Are you certain about that? From what I see, selecting inevitably gives focus, and removing the focus inevitably removes the selection.

Comment: Mhm, I've seen it when interacting with selections and focus via the APIs. Tho i wouldn't be surprised if its not possible via user input.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if a element is selected with something like:

```
document.getElementById("color-red").checked
```

which will return a boolean.

If that's what you want, check out an example at http://jsfiddle.net/o5t0ow9g/1/

Comment: I could be incorrect, but I believe they're referring to text selection, rather than checkbox selection.

Comment: You might be right @Richard, I should have asked the OP to explain his question first.

Answer (score 0):

I think (but am not 100% sure) that if the element is not the active element for the document, it can't have a text selection. You can test it using `document.activeElement`:

```
if (inputFieldDomNode == document.activeElement) {
    // Do stuff with the selection
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/hpseuLj3/1/

Comment: That's what I tried immediately before asking this question. But apparently this isn't the case - if I use setSelectionRange without focusing on it, it remains out of focus (at least on chrome). So it could have false negatives.

Comment: Maybe I can combine tests and do `if(inputFieldDomNode === document.activeElement || inputFieldDomNode.selectionStart !== inputFieldDomNode.selectionEnd)` ? Would that make sense to do?

Comment: No, that doesn't work in all cases either. Testing a bit, if I select a node with my  mouse (making it the active element), then in the console use setSelectionRange to select a range in a different input, the activeElement is still on the first node i selected with my mouse. I can click on the scroll bar to bring the page back into focus (vs the console) and if I press an arrow right, it will respect the caret in the selection, but if I press tab, it pays attention to the node that was in focus.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I figured it out:

```
exports.getSelectionRange = function (element) {
    if(element.nodeName === 'INPUT' || element.nodeName === 'TEXTAREA') {
        var selection = window.getSelection()
        for(var n=0; n<selection.rangeCount; n++) {
            var range = selection.getRangeAt(0)
            if(range.startOffset === range.endOffset && range.startContainer.children[range.startOffset] === element /*|| range.startContainer === element || */) { // I don't think the input or textarea itself will ever be the startContainer
                return [element.selectionStart, element.selectionEnd]
            }
        }
        // else return undefined - the element doesn't have an active caret or active selection (it still may have an inactive selection)
    } else {
        // .. do something else unrelated to this question
    }
}
```

Basically, when you have an active text input, its parent is the `range.startContainer` and so you have to not only check that it is a child of `range.startContaine` but make sure that its the *right* child (the child that's selected) which is determined by the `range.startOffset`. Also, you have to make sure that input is the *only* thing that's selected, because its possible for the input to be included in a larger selection.

Note: I think this might still fail in cases where the actual input node is the only thing selected and *not* its contents. This is an incredibly rare edge case and i'm not sure if its even possible via user input (tho probably possible via the dom API).