# Get DOM element at caret position

Tags: javascript, dom, selection, caret, textselection

I'm looking for a robust way to find where the active caret on the page is. I've learned the following things (at least about chrome):

- Every input and textarea has its own separate caret
- Only one caret can be "active" on the page, meaning that if you press the arrow keys, only one of the carets will be affected
- The active caret does *not* have to be inside the element document.activeElement (e.g. if you use `inputDomNode.setSelectionRange`, whatever element that was previously focused remained in focus).

So I'm basically wondering how to figure out which caret will move when you press an arrow key.

Comment: This is related to the quesion: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28625615/how-can-i-tell-if-a-text-input-field-dom-node-does-not-have-a-selection-with-j/28638322#28638322

Answer (score 0):

You might want to have a look at the Selection API and `window.getSelection()`.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.getSelection
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection

In your example, if you wish to know which (if any) textarea the window's caret is currently in, this should do the trick:

```
var ta, // textarea element
    f = window.getSelection ? window.getSelection().focusNode : undefined
if (f) {
   // if the textarea is empty, the focusNode ought to be the textarea
   if (f.nodeType === 1 && f.tagName === "textarea") {
      ta = f;
   } else if (f.nodeType === 3 && f.parentNode
              && f.parentNode.tagName === "textarea") {
      ta = f.parentNode;
   }
} else {
   // Selection API is not supported in this browser (< IE9)
   // And you will have to use another method to determine the window's
   //  current selection.
}
```

Please note that the Selection API is not supported in old versions of IE.

Comment: So at least in chrome, the focusNode isn't the input element. Its the input element's parent for some reason.